# How to dynamically add an action to a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I noticed I had a lot of functions to dynamically add buttons in one of my view controllers, which clearly goes against the DRY principle.

To fix this, I wrote a hit-everything `configureButton` function:

```
func configureButton (button: UIButton, action: String, title: String, pos: [CGFloat]) {
    button.addTarget(self, action: action,
            forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    // ^ throws an error

    // button.addTarget(self, action: "goToScanner",
    //        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    /* configure everything else */        

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

When I had a zillion different functions, I simply wrote something like

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "goToScanner",    // <-- note the string
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

in each of them, where `"goToScanner"` is the function I want called on tap.

I want to be able to dynamically pass the action parameter for `button.addTarget` to `configureButton`:

```
configureButton(scanButton, action: "goToScanner", title: "Scan", pos: [36.0, 300])
```

I tried passing a closure `() -> ()`, but that didn't work.

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should be

```
func configureButton (button: UIButton, action: Selector, title: String, pos: [CGFloat])
```

Note how it uses `Selector` instead of `String`.

This is because Swift has no built in implementation of a `Selector`, **you pass a string and the string literal is type inferred into a `Selector`** (just like how entering a number literal will work as both a int, float, NSNumber, etc).